# how to print all words from the strings where the given letter is repeated three or more times?

Tags: c, string, function

**Task**: create a function with a variable number of parameters that print words from the given strings in which the given letter is repeated three or more times.

I've tried this code below, but I don't know where is a problem, maybe you will tell me what's wrong?

Also, what is important, I didn't use the macros from `<stdarg.h>`, because I have such task.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int count_char(char *str, char c) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        if (str[i] == c) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

void print_words_with_repeated_letter(int k, char *str, ...) {
    int length, j;

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        length = strlen(str);
        j = 0;
    }
    while (j < length) {
        char *word = strtok(str, " ");
        while (word != NULL) {
            for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++) {
                int char_count = count_char(word, word[i]);
                if (char_count >= 3) {
                    printf("Words with repeated letter: %s\n", word);
                }
            }
            word = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char str1[] = "This is a sample sentenceccc.";
    char str2[] = "Another sentence, with more wooords.";
    print_words_with_repeated_letter(2, str1, str2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to handle variable arguments, you should use the macros from `<stdarg.h>`. Note also that using the length of the string to test if all words have been handled is inappropriate. You should instead test if `strtok()` returns `NULL`.  `strtok` however modifies the string, which is a side effect that should be avoided.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// test if the string contains a character repeated at least 3 times
int check_repeat3(const char *str, size_t len) {
    unsigned char count[256] = { 0 };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (++count[(unsigned char)str[i]] >= 3)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void print_words_with_repeated_letter(int k, ...) {
    const char *separators = " \t\n";
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, k);

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        char *str = va_arg(ap, char *);
        while (*str) {
            size_t n;
            str += strspn(str, separators);
            n = strcspn(str, separators);
            if (check_repeat3(str, n)) {
                printf("%.*s\n", (int)n, str);
            }
            str += n;
        }
    }
    va_end(ap);
}

int main(void) {
    char str1[] = "This is a sample sentenceccc.";
    char str2[] = "Another sentence, with more wooords.";
    print_words_with_repeated_letter(2, str1, str2);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
sentenceccc.
sentence,
wooords.
```

You might want to consider punctuation as word separators. Extra characters can be added to the list of separators:

```
    const char *separators = " \t\n.,:;!?()";
```

Answer (score 1):

The key changes that were made include:

Added a loop over k in the print_words_with_repeated_letter function, which allows us to repeat the process of checking for repeated letters in multiple strings.
Added a break statement in the innermost loop of the function, which allows us to skip the rest of the characters in a word if we find one that is repeated three or more times.
Modified the way the strtok function is used to ensure that we don't skip over words in the input strin

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int count_char(char* str, char c) {
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
  if (str[i] == c) {
      count++;
  }
}
return count;
}

void print_words_with_repeated_letter(int k, char* str) {
int length, j;

for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
  length = strlen(str);
  j = 0;
  while (j < length) {
    char* word = strtok(str+j, " ");
    if (word == NULL) {
        break;
    }
    int word_length = strlen(word);
    for (int i = 0; i < word_length; i++) {
        int char_count = count_char(word, word[i]);
        if (char_count >= 3) {
            printf("Words with repeated letter: %s\n", word);
            break;
        }
    }
    j += strlen(word) + 1;
  }
}
}

int main() {
char str1[] = "This is a sample sentenceccc.";
char str2[] = "Another sentence, with more wooords.";
print_words_with_repeated_letter(1, str1);
print_words_with_repeated_letter(1, str2);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {` not very good 2. The sentence has more delimiters than the space. 3. `strlen` does not return `int`